# bash need STDOUT+STDERR in log, and STDERR to its normal destination

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, logging, stderr

This is a cron job, and the output to STDERR results in an email notification of an error, which I need. However, the errors may be non-fatal, so I also need the STDERR output included in the log with STDOUT. How?

Comment: this gets asked 1-2 x per month. Didn't you find anything that will help? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I spent a few minutes working out how to do this with just the standard shell command line.

Prepare yourself for a ridiculous command line.

```
((./your-script 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | tee /dev/fd/2) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- ) |
    cat >logfile
```

The only thing I can say about that abomination is that it works... and I can't find anything simpler that also works. Oh, and, it doesn't require `bash` or anything. It works in standard bourne shell.

I haven't got a clue why there has to be `| cat` near the end, but it doesn't work without it.

Comment: Adding `cat` at the end changes the line buffering mode, so you'd see the output sooner (perhaps), but I would expect it to be all the same in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The following command works with less characters:

```
((./your-script 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3- | tee /dev/fd/2) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3- ) | cat > logfile
```